# python : Mapping a combination of columns values to extract list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4], "col2":[5,6,7,8]})
df
   col1  col2
0     1     5
1     2     6
2     3     7
3     4     8
```

I have a list:

```
ls = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "ij"]
```

I need to map combination of col1 and col2 to index of list such that 1 and 5 gets mapped to b and f. The final dataframe I need is :

```
df
   col1  col2 item1 item2
0     1     5     b     f
1     2     6     c     g
2     3     7     d     h
3     4     8     e    ij
```

I tried generating all possible pairs from the list using `itertools.combinations` and then mapped it to the pandas dataframe. But this works only for small list. My actual list contains > 5000 items and hence I get memory error if I use itertools. Please let me know if there is a better solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate` with `map`

**Ex:**

```
ls = dict(enumerate(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "ij"]))
# --> {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'ij'}

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4], "col2":[5,6,7,8]})
df["item1"] = df['col1'].map(ls) 
df["item2"] = df['col2'].map(ls)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   col1  col2 item1 item2
0     1     5     b     f
1     2     6     c     g
2     3     7     d     h
3     4     8     e    ij
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `applymap`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4], "col2":[5,6,7,8]})

ls = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "ij"]

df[["item1","item2"]] = df.applymap(lambda x: ls[x])

print (df)

#
   col1  col2 item1 item2
0     1     5     b     f
1     2     6     c     g
2     3     7     d     h
3     4     8     e    ij
```

Comment: `df.applymap(ls.__getitem__)`

Answer (score 0):

Convert list `ls` to numpy array and just simply fancy index and assign to columns

```
arr = np.array(ls)
df['item1'], df['item2'] = arr[df.values].T

print(df)

Out[85]:
   col1  col2 item1 item2
0     1     5     b     f
1     2     6     c     g
2     3     7     d     h
3     4     8     e    ij
```